# pipe system call

Tags: c, ssh, posix, pipe

can someone give me simple example in c, of using pipe() system call to and use ssh to connect to a remote server and execute a simple ls command and parse the reply. thanks in advance,..

Comment: You might want to update your question regarding pipe&ssh.

Comment: They probably can. But it's going to be two different examples - one for pipe(), another for ssh().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    const char host[] = "foo.example.com";  // assume same username on remote
    enum { READ = 0, WRITE = 1 };
    int c, fd[2];
    FILE *childstdout;

    if (pipe(fd) == -1
     || (childstdout = fdopen(fd[READ], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("pipe() or fdopen() failed");
        return 1;
    }
    switch (fork()) {
      case 0:  // child
        close(fd[READ]);
        if (dup2(fd[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO) != -1)
            execlp("ssh", "ssh", host, "ls", NULL);
        _exit(1);
      case -1: // error
        perror("fork() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd[WRITE]);
    // write remote ls output to stdout;
    while ((c = getc(childstdout)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    if (ferror(childstdout)) {
        perror("I/O error");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note: the example doesn't parse the output from `ls`, since no program should ever do that. It's unreliable when filenames contain whitespace.

Comment: the file system is in such a way that it doesnt contain white spaces.. anyways can i use the output to get data?? i mean use ls and get the list of files to a structure or vector or list or something like that???

Comment: You're getting `ls` output in a `FILE *` stream, so you can do with it whatever you can do with a stream, except `fseek`.

Comment: thank you very much. it works. how would i change the pgm for multiple commands? like a cd command and then an ls command.

Comment: If I understand correctly that you want to do a `cd` *on the remote end*, then you have to pass it to the `ssh` command. I.e., `execlp("ssh", "ssh", host, "(cd 'DIR' && ls)", NULL);` Check out `exec(3)` and `ssh(1)`, and be aware of shell quoting rules if you're going to get the `DIR` argument from user input.

Answer (score 1):

[`pipe(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) creates a pair of file descriptors, one for reading, the other for writing, that are connected to each other. Then you can [`fork(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) to split your process into two and have them talk to each other via these descriptors.

You cannot "connect" to pre-existing process using `pipe(2)`.